# update entity after search

Tags: graph, cosmicmind

I want to update information in my graph entity named type[USERS] with properties:
but when update a particular entity after search, it was duplicated.
Thank you

```
let existElement = graph.searchForEntity(properties: [(key: "username", value: username),("id", id)])


if existElement.count == 1 {

          existElement[0]["id"] = id
          existElement[0]["username"] = username
          existElement[0]["password"] = password
          existElement[0]["nome"] = nome
          existElement[0]["data_cerazione"] = NSDate()

            // salviamoIlDatabase
            graph.async() { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) in
                if let e = error { // se c'è un errore...
                    print(e.localizedDescription) // lo stampiamo in console
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What version of Graph are you using? I think you are asking about the duplication being an issue? By the sounds of your statement, this sounds more like a GitHub issue.

Comment: hi, thanks for replay, my version is the last update on gitHub